# Extracting data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

```
table1

eventcode       mobile         points   name
-------------
CAMTRIP         82074626         10      SS
TARANAKI        91262063         30      JL
CAMTRIP         91262063         10      JL
```

and table2

```
passcode    serial  remark
----------
TARANAKI        1   NZ 
CAMTRIP         2   Cameroon
```

I want an output as

```
Cameroon
NAME Points
----------
SS   10
JL   10

NZ
----------
JL   30
```

I am trying

```
SELECT ( b.name )      name, 
       ( b.points )    point, 
       ( b.eventcode ) ecode, 
       ( c.remark )    rem 
FROM   table1 b, 
       table2 c 
WHERE  c.passcode = b.eventcode 
GROUP  BY b.eventcode
```

I don't get the desired result. what is wrong?

Comment: Would you edit the question to include the desired result please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I guess the actual result you need is:

```
Remark    Name  Points
----------------------
Cameroon  SS    10
Cameroon  JL    10
NZ        JL    30
```

Making Cameroon and NZ group headers should be done in the client. The query for that would be:

```
SELECT t2.Remark, t1.Name, t1.Points
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.passcode = t1.eventcode
```

Just `JOIN` on the shared field, then `SELECT` whatever fields you want from each table.

Comment: Why go with table2 and an inner join on table1 instead of using table1 and a left join to table2. I suspect the OP would want the results where the `Remark` is not set as well. Otherwise, we're totally on the same page regarding presentation not being the db job.

Comment: But remark is his group header, so it seemed more likely to me that all results should fit under a header. Either way only the OP can know what he wants. For the data provided both joins produce the same result so there's no way to know other than guessing.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. If i would want to pivot the presentation of table with remarks as rows and points listed below. How should i do? the remarks are dynamically added.

Comment: I'm not especially clear on PIVOTs, but there are many questions on SO explaining them, try looking at [some of these](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=stackoverflow+mysql+pivot&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=zJr8UsO3BcHLhAe3rIHoDw), I suspect you probably need the columns to be dynamic, which the 5th result explains (although I'm not sure how clearly).

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$query = "Select b.name as name, b.points as points, b.eventcode as ecode, c.remark as rem from table1 b join table2 c ON (c.passcode=b.eventcode) group by b.eventcode";
```

Comment: Thats going to return the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  b.name  as    name, 
        b.points as    point, 
        b.eventcode as ecode, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.remark.has SEPARATOR ", ") as    rem 
FROM   table1 b 
left outer join table2 c on c.passcode = b.eventcode 
GROUP  BY c.passcode
```

Comment: Even this gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
select table2.remark,table1.name,table1.points from table1,table2 where  
table1.eventcode=table2.passcode
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no realistic reason in a database response to need to break up the rows by remark, since this would only be to the benefit of a human user looking at the results, which is not what the response is intended for. Breaking up the results into something easier to view should be handled by a UI layer. With that in mind, the following will get the results you have in mind so that some other process can easily prepare the data for a report:

```
SELECT remark, name, points
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON eventcode = passcode
```

Which would return:

```
remark     name  points
------------------------
Cameroon   SS    10
Cameroon   JL    10
      NZ   JL    30
```