# Mysql dynamic pivoting and groupoing

Tags: php, mysql

Following up on my question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749492/extracting-data-from-2-tables/21749694#21749694)

I have a table1

```
Remark    Name  Points
----------------------
Cameroon  SS    10
Cameroon  JL    10
NZ        JL    30
```

I want to display it as

```
       NZ   Cameroon
---------------------
 JL    10      10
 SS     0      30
```

the entries of table1 in remark are dynamic and more will be added.

What i am trying in Php is

```
$query_get = "SELECT DISTINCT remark FROM table1";
$result =  mysql_query($query_get) or die(mysql_error());
$remarks ='';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
$remarks .= ",SUM( IF( remark={$row[0]}, 1, 0 ) ) as {$row[0]} ";
};


$query = "SELECT name, .$eventcodes. FROM jr_event_points";
$result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Now the error comes at query. how should i proceed for second query once i have dynamic column summed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it on MySQL side with dynamic SQL

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN remark = ''', 
                                    remark, 
                                    ''' THEN points END), 0) `',
                                    remark,
                                    '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name, ', @sql, ' FROM table1 GROUP BY name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| NAME | CAMEROON | NZ |
|------|----------|----|
|   JL |       10 | 30 |
|   SS |       10 |  0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57bbc6/4)** demo

---

> *If i want to do it by php, is it possible?*

```sql
$sql = "
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN remark = ''', 
                                    remark, 
                                    ''' THEN points END), 0) `',
                                    remark,
                                    '`')) columns
  FROM table1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die ('Error: ' . mysql_error()); //TODO: better error handling
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sql = "SELECT name, {$row['columns']} FROM table1 GROUP BY name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die ('Error: ' . mysql_error()); //TODO: better error handling
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '| '. implode(' | ', array_keys($row)) . ' |' . PHP_EOL;
echo '| '. implode(' | ', array_values($row)) . ' |' . PHP_EOL;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '| '. implode(' | ', array_values($row)) . ' |' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
| name | Cameroon | NZ |
| JL | 10 | 30 |
| SS | 10 | 0 |
```

**Note:** consider to switch from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` since this extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Comment: If i want to do it by php, is it possible?

Comment: @user3305121 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?